# waiting a specific amount of time for process to run

Tags: linux, process

```
int run() {
int status;
pid_t pid = fork();
if(pid == 0) {  /* Child. */
    execl(OBJECT_FILE, OBJECT_FILE, NULL);
    return 0;
}
else {
    if(pid == -1) {
        write(2, FORK_FAIL, sizeof(FORK_FAIL));
        _exit(1);
    }
    //need to fill
}}
```

In the aforementioned function I'm running some .o code from a child process, and I want to return OBJECT_FILE return value. However, I want to wait for it to finish for at most 3 seconds, and if it didn't finish, I would return -1. How it can be done? (By the way, I'm working on linux)